# Using Alt Codes for drop down in Navigation

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have this navigation and I am using Alt Codes "▼" (Alt+31) to show the drop down with the following CSS.

```
ul>li.drop_down>a:before
{
content: "▼"
}
```

Are there any pontential issues here or am I just better off using a background-image for this purpose. By pontential issues I mean, but not limited to, the character not showing up in different OS or UA and such.

I am using UTF-8 without BOM, New Doc Format = Unix and EOL = Unix Format (don't know if this info will be needed or not).

Comment: First off, I'd suggest using `&#x25BC;` instead of writing the character out, the second thing to remember is to use a font that has the character available.

Comment: `:before` won't work in legacy (IE) browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file and the http headers has the right codification, I think you will not have any problem with this character.

Fonts that support "▼" (Unicode Block 'Geometric Shapes'):

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/geometric_shapes/fontsupport.htm

As you can see, Arial supports it (you can found this font in almost every computer):

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/arial/blockview.htm?block=geometric_shapes

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Unicode for these sorts of things. For ▼ in particular, it's `\25bc`.

I.e.

```
ul > li.drop_down > a::before
{
    content: "\25bc";
}
```

Also, note that I used `::before` – this is the technically correct formation, but certain versions of IE require that you use `:before` (and as far as I am aware, everything recognizes it even though it's non-standard). You probably want `:before` even though `::before` is correct.